# Connecting to sharepoint on premises throught C# with TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, ssl, sharepoint, tls1.2

I had working Word plugin, which connected to our sharepoint directories. But after our admins did the change, it is not working and I am getting error:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: Could not create
>   SSL/TLS secure channel.'

They told me that they updated the **TLS**. How can I force **C#** to use **TLS 1.2** or **1.3** while connecting. I think that it is using **1.1** or **1.2** by default.

```
        int ConnectionTest = 0; //will try to connect once
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://some.com/some");
        //Configure the handler that will add the header.
        ctx.ExecutingWebRequest +=
        new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(ctx_MixedAuthRequest);
        //Set the Windows credentials.
        ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
        ctx.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //Get the web.
        Web w = ctx.Web;
        //Load lists with all properties. 
        List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        try
        {
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch
        { ConnectionTest = 1; }
        if (ConnectionTest == 0)
        {
            ctx.Load(list);
            ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
            ctx.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
            ctx.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
            List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();
            foreach (Folder f in fcol)
            {
                if (f.Name == "Mallid")
                {
                    ctx.Load(f.Folders);
                    ctx.Load(f.Files);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    FolderCollection folderCol = f.Folders;
```

Comment: I answered a similar question a few months ago.  The OP used OR to (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) select which versions to use.  Even though more than one was selected if the server did not automatically try all selected.  Some servers are not designed to work with more than on version.  The OP had to try each one manually until the server accepted a compatible version.  When a client and server connect there is a negotiation using the headers in client and server to find a compatible mode.

Comment: Yes, thank you. After adding `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |=
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; ` it is working.

Comment: Can you please try `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` on top

Comment: Yes it is working now thanks :)

Comment: Is this ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; added before or added after the ctx.ExecutingWebRequest...?

Comment: You need to set properties before making actual connection.